# Как организовать связь категорий с подкатегориями в сериализаторе rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Я изучаю DRF и хотелось бы получить помощь. У меня есть модели с категориями и подкатегориями, мне бы хотелось выводить в сериализаторе при выборе категории выводились подкатегории относящиеся к этой категории. Такое можно организовать в сериализаторе?

Models:

```py
class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    """Основная категория"""
    name = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length=120)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория продукта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории продуктов'


class SubCategoryProduct(models.Model):
    """Подкатегория"""
    name = models.CharField('Название подкатегории', max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория подкатегория')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Подкатегория продукта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Подкатегории продуктов'
```

serializer:

```py
class CategorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.CategoryProduct
        fields = ('name',)


class SubCategoryProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # category = CategorySerializers()
    class Meta:
        model = models.SubCategoryProduct
        fields = ('name', 'category')
```

Сейчас получается какую бы я категорию не выбирал, в подкатегориях получаю весь список.
Или это реализуется на frontend.
Я пытаюсь на текущий момент реализовать это в форме rest framework при отправке POST запроса.

---

Как я понял это нужно организовать на Frontend.

models

```
class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    """Основная категория"""
    name = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length=120)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160)

class SubCategoryProduct(models.Model):
    """Подкатегория"""
    name = models.CharField('Название подкатегории', max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория подкатегория')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160)

class Product(models.Model):
    """Модель объявлений товаров"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория адс')
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategoryProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Подкатегория адс')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название объявления', max_length=160)
```

Comment: [Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: создаете эндпоинт, по которому будут доступны все категории, затем содаете эндпоинт, по которому будут доступны подкатегории. на фронте при выборе какой-либо категории отправляется на бэк запрос всех подкатегорий для категории с таким-то `id`

Answer (score 0):

Конечно это надо реализовывать на DRF. Задача сводится к тому, что бы отфильтровать SubCategoryProduct по связям с ForeignKey(CategoryProduct. Вам потребуется переписать serializer с использованием SerializerMethodField(). В Вашем случае код будет примерно таким:

```
class SubCategoryProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SubCategoryProduct
        fields = '__all__'


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub_category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CategoryProduct
        fields = ('name', 'sub_category')

    def get_sub_category(self, obj):
        queryset = SubCategoryProduct.objects.filter(category=obj)
        return [SubCategoryProductSerializer(q).data for q in queryset]
```

Ваш View должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
class SubCategoryProductCreateView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = SubCategoryProductSerializer(
            data=request.data,
            )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Я наверное не правильно выразился, я хочу чтобы в форму подтягивались подкатегории. У drf есть html форма для запроса, можно ли в ней это организовать. Я сделал ещё один сериализатор и пытался ваш способ вывести через него. В get запросе на вывод данных это работает, но в форме у меня пропадают категории почему-то.

Comment: Так, давайте разберёмся. Вы хотите отправлять POST, что бы добавить к категории ещё одну подкатегорию?

Comment: Да, я хочу при отправки post, чтобы в форме выбирается категория, после выбора категории в форме выбирается подкатегория отфильтрованная по категории. На странице с пост запросом у меня получается форма категории подкатегория и описание. Возможно у меня ошибка в моделях, т.к и подкатегория и категория в модели через ForeignKey к другим моделями. В сериализаторе post у меня не определены сериализаторы для полей категория и подкатегория, сериализатор берет данные из модели поста.

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса свои модели.

Comment: Нет, ForeignKey тут не при чём. Не могу понять, если вы с помощью метода POST хотите добавить ещё одну подкатегорию к категории, зачем Вам выпадающий список с подкатегориями? В общем, тогда у вас должен запрос отправляться с фронтенда в формате json на конечную точку с полями 'name', 'url' и 'id' категории. Id категорий надо брать из конечной точки со списком всех категорий. Больше информации https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/. Для тестирования своего API используйте Postman(для тестов используйте метод form-post). Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, нет я не с помощью поста хочу, просто хочу чтоб в форме при выборе категории подгружались подкатегории для выбора относящиеся к этой категории.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в этом направлении https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643204/django-rest-framework-dynamically-return-subset-of-fields